# How to deserialize JSON data in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have following JSON data, class and code but it doesn't working. I am getting List of 3 object but all are NULL. Can anybody please suggest me what I am missing here?

JSON data:

```
[
    {
        "donotpostalmail": {
            "Do Not Allow": {
                "Do Not Allow": 1
            },
            "Allow": {
                "Allow": 0
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "familystatuscode": {
            "Single": {
                "Single": 1
            },
            "Married": {
                "Married": 2
            },
            "Divorced": {
                "Divorced": 3
            },
            "Widowed": {
                "Widowed": 4
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "preferredcontactmethodcode": {
            "Any": {
                "Any": 1
            },
            "Email": {
                "Email": 2
            },
            "Phone": {
                "Phone": 3
            },
            "Fax": {
                "Fax": 4
            },
            "Mail": {
                "Mail": 5
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Class:

```
public class ResponseDataOfOptions
{
    public OptionsList mainList { get; set; }
}
public class OptionsList
{
    public Dictionary<string, Options> optionList { get; set; }
}
public class Options
{
    public Dictionary<string, int> options { get; set; }
}
```

.cs file Code:

```
List<ResponseDataOfOptions> optionList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ResponseDataOfOptions>>(objResponse.ResponseDataOfOptions);
```

Comment: I believe your issue is mapping the response to a dictionary. Have you tried using something like http://json2csharp.com to build the classes? Admittedly I haven't worked with Json -> dict before, but that should be the issue.

Comment: I have tried. It has provided me really poor class for above JSON. So, I tried by my self. Usually, json2csharp.com doesn't provide better solution if JSON is based on Dictionary.

Comment: Your object model in no way represents your JSON data - how do you expect any deserializer to know where to put what values?

Comment: @Jamiec Can you please suggest Class which can represent above JSON?

Comment: @NanjiMange no, because there isnt one. Your only option is a hierarchy of dictionaries or a `JObject` as described in one of the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use objects in this case because every object has different property names. The only way to deserialize this JSON is as follows.

```
 JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<
      Dictionary<string, 
          Dictionary<string, 
              Dictionary<string, int>
          >
      >
 >>(objResponse.ResponseDataOfOptions);
```

It is a list of dictionaries, in fact there are three levels of dictionaries. It's not a very friendly structure to work with data but that would do the deserialize.

You might also be interested in using some property detection using `JObject` and `JToken` and then inflate appropriate data transfer objects.

```
JObject list = JObject.Parse(objResponse.ResponseDataOfOptions);
foreach (var item in list) {
    JToken token = jobj["donotpostalmail"];
    if (token != null) {
        // inflate the corresponding data type.
    }
}
```

Comment: I have created Dictionary in separate class same way you have represented here. I think I have tried this already. Let me try again.

Comment: You cannot use data transfer objects because of the different property names. Even though, there is a less neat way to parse JSON that might help you, I just added it to the answer.

Comment: I have used first method. It is working fine. It would be greatly helpful if class structure is possible. Well, this is greate solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use an array that contains 3 different objects types.
If you want to do this, I recommend to use a container object instead of an array:

```
{
    "responseDataOfOptions": {
        "donotpostalmail": {
            "Do Not Allow": {
                "Do Not Allow": 1
            },
            "Allow": {
                "Allow": 0
            }
        }
    },
    "optionsList": {
        "familystatuscode": {
            "Single": {
                "Single": 1
            },
            "Married": {
                "Married": 2
            },
            "Divorced": {
                "Divorced": 3
            },
            "Widowed": {
                "Widowed": 4
            }
        }
    },
    "options": {
        "preferredcontactmethodcode": {
            "Any": {
                "Any": 1
            },
            "Email": {
                "Email": 2
            },
            "Phone": {
                "Phone": 3
            },
            "Fax": {
                "Fax": 4
            },
            "Mail": {
                "Mail": 5
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The corresponding C# class must look like this:

```
public class JsonResponse {
    public ResponseDataOfOptions responseDataOfOptions{ get; set; }
    public OptionsList optionsList{ get; set; }
    public Options options { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It is one of the way if there is no solution. But I got solution.

Answer (score 0):

please check your json string `objResponse.ResponseDataOfOptions` format whether is correct, maybe there are some `&quot;` in your string, if yes, you need to replace these `&quot;` as below:

```
List<ResponseDataOfOptions> optionList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ResponseDataOfOptions>>(objResponse.ResponseDataOfOptions.Replace("&quot;", "\""));
```

Comment: The issue is the JSON string to a dictionary, rather than `optionList` being null.